# MYSQL - Why to create 2 tables and Do INNER JOIN instead of using 1 table only?

Tags: php, mysql, join

MYSQL - Why to create 2 tables and Do INNER JOIN instead of using 1 table only ?

i am creating DB structure and i am using MYISAM as storage engine.
i was looking at some high end paid script to get idea about creating DB structure .

and noticed it has one big table with all the details of posts and one additional table just for storing views count like this.

**db.content**

```
id | title | date | record_num | and | some | others |
```

and

**db.content_views**

```
views | content
```

so when a php page is loaded it does

```
@mysql_query("UPDATE content_views SET views = (views + 1) WHERE content = '$id'");
```

and while showing views on php page it uses Left Join Query like this

```
SELECT content.*, content_views.views as views, users.username as username FROM content LEFT JOIN users ON users.record_num = content.submitter 
LEFT JOIN content_views ON content_views.content = content.record_num WHERE content.record_num = '$id' LIMIT 0,1
```

so my question is as 
Both tables are MYISAM so they both have table locking then why not add views field/column in the main Content Table ?

as while updating the views count its going to wait for lock the table anyways and any other LEft join query will have to wait until the update is done on separate table.

Comment: sometimes it's due to the new fields have been added to the system after the fact, after the main table was filled with data. Adding a column to a table will kill the system while the `alter` is in progress. So if this is on a heavy-use live system, you can't kill the system just to add a new field. So you create a new separate table and put the new field(s) in there.

Comment: updating smaller table costs less

Comment: @MarcB i guess thats the issue , as the paid script has grown so much over time and think that might be case.

Comment: @Peter i doubt it ,as it will be only updating the specific field and not the whole row . still have to check more about it. then how about i create a new MEMORY table and store views count in it and then a hourly script will update the main content table.

Comment: @Peter, edits will be in place. AMB, if you're worried about contention, switch to InnoDB (row locks). Regarding the hourly script, I'd rather have many small hits spread over time than one large one. It scales better.